# SF novella from 90's (possibly) in which ideas are the last life form left after heat death of universe

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the title of a story featuring multiple evil "Nixons" (copies of the idea of Richard Nixon, since nothing biological or mechanical is still around) trying to dominate what's left of the universe after its heat death. Only the memory of the concept of a toy superhero has the possibility of stopping him.

It was probably published in Asimov's or Galaxy magazine back in the eighties or early nineties.

Comment: Probably not the right one, since it's published recently, but "Tricky Dick Nixon and the Heat Death of the Universe" by A.C. Teague kind of fits.

Comment: @Fuzzyboots - How could that *not* be it, with a title like that?